# using fabric.js object:modified event to update underlying model

Tags: fabricjs

In FabricJS I can trap the object:modified event.  I want to use this to update an underlying object model of the canvas.  IE, we have our own definition of a diagram.

I can't see how the event object relates the actual change made to the canvas.  Has anyone seen any documentation or sample for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no differences in the event, compared to the last object state.
You can implement this by yourself.

`object:modified` uses a callback that takes an object as unique arg.

let's call it options. options.target is the object that fired the event.

Each fabric.Object has a mixing with the methods for a stateful inspection that must be trigged manually.

so you can do `rect.saveState('propsINeedToCheck')` and `rect.hasStateChanged('propsINeedToCheck')`

Where `propsINeedToCheck` is an array in the prototype:

`fabric.Object.prototype.propsINeedToCheck = ['top', 'left', 'angle']` that you have to create.

There is nothing right now that tells you what actually changed, just that something is changed. The effectiveness of this method depends on how many things you want to check.

The alternative is to dump an object state each time and compare with a function that does deep comparing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I'll have a look at how to do that.  In the mean time I have created 'simple' way to do this.  I'll post a separate question about that :)  Cheers